Laravel Kernel.php file alternative
Im trying to work with ai on my project in Laravel.
Most of them are a bit outdated, so if I want some scheduling they suggest using kernel.php in app/Console.
I did some research and kernel.php file is now hidden somewhere in new Laravel versions.
Whats the alternative of using kernel?

In laravel 11, kernel.php is no longer present and the related configuration should be handled through the bootstrap/app.php file.
Task scheduling is done in routes/console.php file in laravel 11.
For more detailed information about bootstrap/app.php file you can check this link.
https://laravel-news.com/laravel-11-directory-structure#content-the-app-directory
Also check the release note of the laravel 11 here..
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/releases
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/releases#scheduling
I hope it will help you.

Thank you. For anyone else with this issue, here is the specific section in the release notes mentioned above https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/releases#scheduling

@Thor, Thank you for your comment, I have updated the answer annexing the exact link that you provided here.

Task scheduling can also be done in /bootstrap/app.php using withSchedule:
use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;

->withSchedule(function (Schedule $schedule) {
    $schedule->command('some:signature')->daily();
})

