Cannot register command in Laravel 11
I have just switched from laravel 10 to laravel 11. I have successfully registered my command in laravel 10.
command saved in laravel 10
and now I'm trying to register my command in console.php and bootstrap/app.php for my new project in Laravel 11. Since Kernel.php is no longer included in the app/Console.
command not saved in laravel 11
I have tried to use Schedule::command/Artisan::command and somehow I received an Illuminate\Database\QueryException in Laravel 11 even though the command works everyTenSeconds() successfully in laravel 10 but not in Laravel 11. I can call the command manually but I cannot run it in php artisan schedule:work.

Did you migrate your database because this https://i.sstatic.net/fuXTTa6t.png shows that the crm.cache_locks` doesn't exist?

Check the link,this might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78532447/laravel-kernel-php-file-alternative/78532490#78532490

I was looking for a way to register a command in console.php without the need to migrate a new table in the database. But directly into the storage/framework/cache. Thanks for your comments and suggestions.
